# OpenCV Max Detection Range

Tags: opencv, surf

I am wondering what is the maximum distance of detection/recognition of an image using SURF method? Has any one tried. Camera: Logitech Webcam Pro 9000

Comment: There will be infinite distances :)

Comment: So something 5m away could be detected by using the SURF algo?

Comment: It depends how big it is ...

Comment: So the object is the size of an A4 paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer vision the distance from camera does not really matter. What matters is the expanse size of the object contour. For example you can place a really huge object 10km from camera's object-glass and it could still cover the whole visual field. From CV point of view, it will be the same as having a small object right in front of the camera.

Known info:

- your camera's max resolution: 1600*1200px
- distance of the object: 5m

Unknown info:

- size of the object - Roger Rowland's comment totally hit home ;)
- visual complexity of the object
- environmental conditions between camera and object
- lighting conditions

You are unlikely to detect any objects further than ~2.9 million light-years from Earth without magnifier lenses, but this restriction has more kind of physical nature..