# Max range for object detection

Tags: c++, opencv, detection

I determining the distance of an object from a camera where the object moves towards the camera. Using a webcam I am successfully able to detect the object upto 1 meter but cannot detect beyond it.

I have to agree with the answer in this post [OpenCV Max Detection Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399642/opencv-max-detection-range), where the object contour increases as the object moves towards the camera. The object in question has a size of a tennis ball. Any suggestions to detect the said object at a distance greater 20m ?

Comment: I think you should try to use a camera with greater resolution.

Comment: what kind of detection algorithm do you use? Many algorithms have some minimum detection size (here's meant the object pixel region size in the image). Sometimes you can just resize the image to detect smaller projections, too, but that doesn't work for all kind of detection algorithms and sizes.

Comment: for testing purposes ( i.e calculating the distance of object moving towards camera), the detection is done by converting to HSV format and then looking for circles since the shape of object is always constant. Yes, most algorithms do have have a min size, but the main issue is that beyond a certain distance the object is a very small speck ( for deployment purposes - the camera will be very small - almost that of a raspberry camera module). Also, another question is that does the focal length play a role as well or is it just the resolution of camera ?

Comment: focal length plays a role. Combination of focal length, sensor size, resolution and distance of the object (and distortion) will determine how big your object appears in the image.The bigger the focal length, the bigger the "zoom", because narrower bulb of light rays will hit your camera sensor. So the bigger the focal length, the bigger the object in your image, but the scene you can project will be smaller.